# Spanish equivalent of the verb 'to etiolate'

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

The verb [to etiolate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/etiolate) is, in English quite rare, but since it has a French -> Latin etymology it might have a common term in Spanish.

Is there an equivalent word in Spanish, however archaic, to the English verb *etiolate*?

If there is not an exact equivalent term, are there any others sharing a common definiens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of both words, **etiolar** (verb) or **etiolación** (noun) are included in the Spanish dictionary, but are widely used in botany and gardening. That is, "you're authorized" to use them without problems because they are technical concepts.

To say that a plant loses its color, you can tell **blanquear** (whitening) or **palidecer** (blanching). If you mean that the plant is weakened by lack of light, you can say **ahilar**.

> Algunas de las plantas se han etiolado.
>
> Ha comenzado el proceso de etiolación de algunas de las plantas.
>
> Se ha observado etiolación en algunas de las plantas.
>
> Algunas plantas se han blanqueado *por falta de luz*.
>
> Algunas plantas se han ahilado.

Comment: Qué bonita palabra, [ahilar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1HE95rh). No la conocía y su etimología es la mar de descriptiva.